# Spring-MVC hibernate mapping using anjularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

[BRAND CLASS[Category Class[Controller[Method[AnjularJS Script[Display Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsK6b.png)

I have a problem with Setter and getter method......when i remove it from Brand.java it will wrok without set of category.....but when i add this setter and getter method http://localhost:8080/Sunglasses/getAllBrands this may go in infinite loop for fetch record..what is solution....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an @RestController witch send data to angular app as json and

```
//@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "category" })
public class Brand{

...

@ManyToMany / OneToMany
private Category category; 

... getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class Category{

...

@ManyToMany
private Brand brand;

... getters and setters
}
```

try to add @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "category" })  to Brand class.

Because is a bidirectional relation between category and brand you fetch Brand object and it comes with his category(or list of categories) and category comes with all brand and again and again :)

As an alternative if you want to have all brands and also categories you can add @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "brand" }) to Category.class